# Submitting form from a modal in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to make a registration page in ember which is opened when someone clicks the registration button. The registration page is opened in a modal. I used the modal implementation given on Ember websit
http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/
Now the registration form opens on clicking the button but I am not able to catch the submit event of the registration form anywhere. You can refer to the code here:
    http://jsfiddle.net/jywPL/1/

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{outlet}}
{{outlet modal}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
<h4>Register</h5>
{{outlet}}
<button {{action 'openModal' 'modal' model}}>Register</button>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modal">
{{#modal-dialog action="close"}}
<form class="form-horizontal"  {{action "register" on="submit"}}>
<br/>
<div  align="center" >
<table class="table-hover">
<tr>
    <td>
    <label>First Name</label>
    </td>

    <td>
    {{input value=firstName class="controls" type="text"}}
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    </td>

    <td>
    {{input value=lastName class="controls" type="text"}}
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    <label>Email</label>
    </td>

    <td>
    {{input value=email class="controls" type="text"}}
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    <label>Company</label>
    </td>

    <td>
    {{input value=company class="controls" type="text"}}
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    <label>Company Contact</label>
    </td>

    <td>
    {{input value=contact class="controls" type="text"}}
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
    <label>Reason for request</label>
    </td>

    <td>
    {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="reason" rows="10" cols="20"}}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<button type="submit">Register</button>
<button {{action "close"}}>Done</button>
</div>
</form>

{{/modal-dialog}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/modal-dialog">
 <div class="overlay" {{action "close"}}>
  <div class="modal" {{action bubbles=false}}>
    {{yield}}
  </div>
 </div>
</script>

var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
actions: {
openModal: function(modalName, model) {
  this.controllerFor(modalName).set('model', model);
  return this.render(modalName, {
    into: 'application',
    outlet: 'modal'
  });
},

closeModal: function() {
  return this.disconnectOutlet({
    outlet: 'modal',
    parentView: 'application'
  });
},
register: function() {
    alert('hello');
}
}
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
return Em.Object.create({firstName: '',lastName: '',email:'',company:'',contact:'',reason:''});
},
action: {
register: function(){
    alert('Registering');
}
}
});

App.ModalController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
actions: {
close: function() {
  return this.send('closeModal');
},
register: function(){
alert('hello1');
} 
}
});

App.ModalDialogComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
actions: {
close: function() {
  return this.sendAction();
},
register: function(){
alert('hello2');
}
}
});
```

.I have tried to trigger action helper called register on form submit but the register action is not triggered. From the modal implementation I see that the action bubbling has been disabled so the action wouldn't be triggered in any of the parent routes. But why is it not triggering in ModalDialogComponent actions tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your <strike>ModalController</strike> Route, add

```
action: {
    doRegister: function() {
       this.register(); //or whatever
    }
```

Then on the submit button

```
<button type="submit" {{action "doRegister"}}>Register</button>
```

If your <strike>ModalController</strike> Route is binding correctly, this should work.

Comment: This doesn't work. You can try the example given on ember website. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iluLOto/1/edit. Try adding a button to the modal template next to the done button and put an alert in the action handler for the button. It won't work.

Comment: What do u mean not working? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/udUsEPuY/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: What I meant was that it didn't work in modal controller as you mentioned in answer. Didn't know that action should be defined in ApplicationRoute. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I am accepting the answer. Just edit your answer to point to Application Route as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: alright, but I still believe that actions in Controller will do the job as well.

Comment: ran into same/similar issue... having trouble getting it to work on my end, the working example you showed doesn't have an on="submit action on the button for the form, so while the alert happens, I don't believe it's actually trying to submit the form... with that said, shouldn't it work with the on="submit" on the form clicking the button?